# Why is my local Apache install slow on Windows 7 only with LAN enabled?

Tags: apache-http-server, windows, dns, windows-7, lan

I have a local Wampserver on Windows 7. With the LAN connection disabled, it runs as fast as I would expect. WIth the LAN connection enabled, it waits 20-30 seconds before serving pages either locally on the machine itself across the LAN:

I have tried:

- Disabling IPv6
- Specifying DNS servers explicitly rather than using DHCP to obtain them - no change
- Commenting out '::1 localhost' in the    hosts file  - no change
- Adding/removing various combinations of '127.0.0.1 localhost' in the
  hosts file - no change
- Specifying HostnameLookups Off in Apache and the equivalent in my.ini
  (MySQL skip-name-resolve) -  no change.

I restarted the services after each change.

It does seem to be some kind of DNS lookup issue but I have tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Is the very first request slow, or are some objects on the page you're serving subsequently slow after the initial HTML is downloaded? You can use the Network tab on the Chrome Developer Tools (ctrl+shift+i), httpfox on Firefox, or you could try enabling [mod_log_forensic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_forensic.html) to determine if all or only some objects are slow. Narrowing it down might help determine the cause.

Comment: It was the first request. However, after rebooting the machine, it now seems much faster. So, I have no idea why but the problem is resolved (for now).